# Referencing ADL storage gen2 files from U-SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an ADL account set up with two storages: the regular ADLS gen1 storage set up as a default and a blob storage with "Hierarchical namespace" enabled which is connected to ADLS using storage key if that matters (no managed identities at this point). The first one is unrelated to the question, it just is, the second one for the sake of this question is registered under the name `testdlsg2`. I see both in data explorer in Azure portal.

Now, I have a container in that blob storage called `logs` and at the root of that container there are log files I want to process.

How do I reference those files in that particular storage and that particular container from U-SQL?

I've read the ADLS Gen2 URI [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri) and came up with the following U-SQL:

```
@data =
    EXTRACT
        Timestamp long,
        // skip, skip, skip
        LogDate DateTime,
        LogOrder int
    FROM "abfss://logs@testdlsg2.dfs.core.windows.net/log_{LogDate:yyyy}{LogDate:MM}{LogDate:dd}_{LogOrder}.log.gz"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: ' ', quoting: true, skipFirstNRows: 1);

// the rest is irrelevant
```

Unfortunately, when I submit that to ADL, the job fails with the following error:

> CsEnumerateDirectoryWithPaging failed with error 0x83090A1A (The operation is not supported on the provided Url type). Cosmos Path: abfss://logs@testdlsg2.dfs.core.windows.net/

The query works fine locally when using local storage with relative paths.

Comment: I don't think U-SQL works with ADLSgen2, it's gen1 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, U-SQL does not work with Azure Data Lake Gen 2 and it's unlikely it ever will.  There is a feedback item which you should read:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/36445702-add-support-for-adls-gen2-to-adla

In the year 2020, consider starting new Azure analytics projects with Azure Databricks.

Comment: Hm... What is the point of being able to link ADLS gen2 storage to ADLA if one can't use it?

Comment: You can’t really link ADLS2.  You’re just typing the address and sending it to the compiler.  It’s trying but will never work.  Either stick with ADLA gen 1 or start thinking about alternatives like Azure Databricks.  It’s much more fully featured.

Comment: In Azure portal, ADLA instance settings, there is a Data Explorer tab with the list of data sources.  However it appears as just "Blob storage" there. Either way, I was able to access it using the `wasb` protocol rather than `abfs`.